# Constraint predicate not starting with the maximum value

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I'm trying to get a match for the sum of the first Y elements of a certain list, for Y in the 1..10 range, and for the maximum of the sum. I would like the first match to be Res=10,Y=10, but it is just giving answers starting from Y=1, and increasing to Y=10.
What am I missing here?

```
get_max(Res,Y):-
        Y in 1..10,
        add_list([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],Y,0,Res),
        labeling([max(Y)],[Y,Res]).

add_list(_,0,Res,Res).
add_list([H|Rest],C,Temp,Final):-
        NewTemp #= H+Temp,
        NewC #= C-1,
        add_list(Rest,NewC,NewTemp,Final).

?- get_max(Res,Y).
Res = Y, Y = 1 ;
Res = Y, Y = 2 ;
Res = Y, Y = 3 ;
Res = Y, Y = 4 ;
Res = Y, Y = 5 ;
Res = Y, Y = 6 ;
Res = Y, Y = 7 ;
Res = Y, Y = 8 ;
Res = Y, Y = 9 ;
Res = Y, Y = 10.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could force labeling/2 to take effect swapping the goals in this way:

```erlang
get_max(Res,Y):-
        [Y,Res] ins 1..10,
        labeling([max(Y)],[Y,Res]),
        add_list([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],Y,0,Res).

?- get_max(Res,Y).
Res = Y, Y = 10 ;
Res = Y, Y = 9 .
```

but this requires the declaration on Res' domain as well.

To be true, seems more a bug than a feature.
After all, the solution order should be as you declared, as advertised by library(clpfd).
Otherwise, the clauses' order again come back to bite us...

Answer (score 1):

```
?- add_list([1,1,1,1], Y, 0, Res).
Y = Res, Res = 0 ;
Y = Res, Res = 1 ;
Y = Res, Res = 2 ;
Y = Res, Res = 3 ;
Y = Res, Res = 4.
```

This goal enumerates values for `Y` and `Res` in this order. Labeling is not needed because the values are sufficiently determined. Later labeling also cannot force a different order once this goal enumerates the solutions like this.

(Also, if all you want to do is sum a list, you don't need this many arguments to the predicate. If you named them better, you might also see this. Your `C` had better be named `UselessCounterFromZeroTowardsNegativeInfinity`. Then you could eliminate it.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm specifically trying to understand constraint programming though, and in particular the labeling max option. I'm looking to understand why the get_max output does not start with Y=10.

Comment: The `get_max` answer sequence does not start with `Y = 10` for the reason I said. Try removing the `labeling` goal completely: `get_max` will behave exactly the same way. Labeling does not do anything here, and it cannot change the order of answers here. It can only change the order of answers in problems where *search* is needed. But no search is needed to find the answer to `1 + 1`.

Comment: Indeed so. What would you do then when you want to efficiently use variables that are bounded by constraints as input to goals that dont need search? It would be impossible to use the labeling max option to get the Res of the max Y first?

Comment: You need to change the preceding computation accordingly. In this case, if you exchange the two clauses of `add_list`, it will produce its answers the other way round, starting from the largest. But you must make sure to always call it with the first argument bound to a finite list, otherwise it will not terminate.